# Lightning Web Component JS file ; For -of instead of For-if

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Is there any way to use for of instead of for if for the wire element as given below in the code.

```
@wire(getGlobalConstants, { key: '$destinationNumberlab4'})
    wiredResult(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            let data = result.data;
            for (let key in data) {
             if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (this.destinationNum4) {
                   this.destinationNum4=data[key];
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, can you please edit your question and explain exactly what problem you are facing?

Comment: @rahul I just want to use of instead of in , and want to know what will the impact? and how it works

Comment: @rahul gawaleI just Want to Use Of(for (let key in data))   Instead of in in the for , i am not able to do that as i am getting error as data is not iterable.

Comment: `for..of` can be used only for iterables, to use object properties you need to use `for..in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every Object is not iterable by default**
So you need to use `for..in` with objects. otherwise, you need to convert it into iterable object.

### [For..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over **iterable
>   objects**, including: built-in `String`, `Array`, array-like objects
>   (e.g., `arguments` or `NodeList`), `TypedArray`, `Map`, `Set`, and `user-defined`
>   `iterables`. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be
>   executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

### [For..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The for...in statement iterates over all `enumerable` properties of an
>   object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols),
>   including inherited enumerable properties.

---

See, below code gives error = `Error: obj is not iterable`

```
const obj = {a : 'asas', b:'dfsdf'};

for (const element of obj) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

---

The below code runs successfully and gives output

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (const element of array1) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Output

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

Comment: is there any way i can use for of here?

Comment: you need to convert that into map, but wouldn't recommend that because you can use for..in directly